# Mock imported module in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have a module called 'com' doing low-level serial communication. This module is used by higher level modules to communicate.
I'm trying to add proper unit tests to these modules, but I don't want to make the tests dependent on the serial communication.
So I need to mock out the 'com' module, to emulate responses from serial communication.

Manually I would do that with simply changing the import line:

```
import mymodule.com
```

to something like:

```
import mymodule.mocked_com as com
```

But I know this is not a good approach ... so trying to use mock.patch decoration, without success:

```
@mock.patch('mymodule.com', returns=(True, 'Test'))
def test_myfunction(capsys):
    result, message = controller.myfunction('Something', 'command')
    assert(result)
    assert(message == 'Test')
    out, err = capsys.readouterr()
```

On some reason I never have the desired result returned from "com", but receive an error: "ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mock.patch` decorator is mocking the relative path you provide. Which means that in module X that you are testing if you import and use `com` this way:

```
import com
com.my_awesome_call()
```

In the test of X module you should patch com this way (considering X is at the source):

```
@mock.patch('X.com', ...)
def test_myfunct(mock_com):
    # Boom Badaboom test things
```

Comment: That was what I missed! I added the relative path for the specific method of the "com" module, and referenced the mocking method from a mock module. Working fine now.